# docker-compose update container PATH

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to use docker-compose yml file to update the container's PATH.

```
environment:
   - PATH="$PATH":/my/new/path
```

But when I start the container, it says

oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH"

Is it possible to update the container's PATH from docker-compose yml file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing is updating the PATH, however the error is resulting from the fact that `$PATH` is being expanded to the env variable's value that is on the **host**.

What you can do is figure the `PATH` value that is inside the container by default and appending to that value:

1. Start the image without the variable:
   `docker-compose up`
2. `docker exec -it <container-name> bash`
3. run `echo $PATH` and copy the value
4. replace the value in the compose file:

---

```
environment:
   - PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/my/new/path
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the error occurred when I was trying to execute my startup script `command: bash startup.sh` in docker-compose.

The problem was that my image build was made on `alpine`  Linux which uses **ash** as shell instead of **bash**. Just double check that you are referring to correct shell interpreter. As well check that your `sh` scripts referring to correct unix shell e.g `#!/bin/ash`